# Python Script on Startup:: ValueError:numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 40 from PyObject

Tags: python, numpy

****The Error occurs only with the shell script after reboot!****

**The issue**:

I am trying to run my python script on Startup in Raspberry Pi. So, I wrote a *Shell script* called `launcher.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
# launcher.sh
# navigate to the home directory, then to this directory, then execute python script, then back home

cd /
cd home/pi/myfile
python myfile.py &
cd /
```

After rebooting the Raspberry Pi, I get `ValueError:numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 40 from PyObject` in **cronlog**.

**Solutions available**:

This error is not new and lots of online resources are available [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68478456/solved-error-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility),[2](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5270),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp), etc.I followed these links and installed `pycocotools` and upgraded `numpy`. I get no error when I run my python script in the terminal (`python myfile.py`) and also when I run the shell script (`sh launcher.sh`).

However, after I reboot the Raspberry Pi, the error occurs. What has happened here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a rigorous search, I got some hints from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271941/toad-error-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-ex) accepted answer. I checked my **cronlog** file and followed the python `import` attempt until the error had occurred. The error had occurred just after **import Interval** attempt. Therefore, I installed the `numpy` as follows:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade numpy Interval
```

It solved my problem. Everything works fine after the reboot.